# What do you call this type of elevator?

Tags: single-word-requests

See picture -- is there a better term than *glass elevator*?

[image]

Comment: I've often thought that it was interesting that we call them elevators at all, given that they spend 50% of their time going down, not up... ;-)

Comment: @mickeyf - it may not be that it 'elevates' you, but that it changes your 'elevation'.

Comment: I call them awesome.  I don't know about you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[I used to work in an elevator company]

We usually referred to these as "panoramic elevators". (Google returns a few hundred thousand hits on this).

Comment: _panoramic elevator_ (with quotes): 571 thousand, pictures

Answer (score 4):

*Observation elevator* or *sightseeing elevator*.

I think *observation elevator* is more commonly used, as Google returns pictures and more results (76 thousand vs. 44 thousand, with quotes).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you are referring to the glass-ness of them, or the 'inside-out-ness', in which case you could say 'external elevator', though I've no idea if that's the 'official' term.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in some parts of the anglosphere, "glass lift" (or indeed panoramic lift) is a better term :-)